# Postgres: How to copy elements from text array column into a json column?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a text array column and now I would like to create a new JSON column. In JSON column I would like to create key-value pairs from text array and current time stamp.

**Example:**

Text array `{"aa", "bb", "cc"}` -> JSON `{"aa":"12:00", "bb":"12:00", "cc":"12:00"}`

How do I update this way all rows in the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the current column is named `data` and the new column is `new_data` you can do something like this:

```
update the_table
  set new_data = x.new_data
from (
  select id, jsonb_object_agg(t.k, to_char(now(), 'hh24:mi')) as new_data
  from the_table, unnest(data) as t(k)
  group by id
) x
where x.id = foo.id;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/SMBH72985